# How do I create gift cards through the API

Tags: gift-card

I'm pretty new to the Magento ecosystem and am working with a Magento client who wants to build extra functionality that requires creating gift cards through the API. After scouring for a while I still can't get a clear answer as to if this is possible. For example in Shopify, there is https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/gift-card#post-gift-cards and in Big Commerce there is https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-content/marketing/gift-certificates. Is there an equivalent in Magento? Really appreciate all info thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Every Magento 2 installation has a swagger page and from this  swagger page you can see all API points.  See the details at [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/generate-local.html).

If you are using **Magento 2 cloud Or Enterprise version** then on Swagger you can see GiftCart create Url and also need an access token to access the page. I prefer to use  Integration tokens to access get full API list. To Generate access Integration tokens you can [follow](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) .

Comment: thank you Amit! This is super helpful, thanks for linking the correct documentation!